# Having Issues with assigning Object to DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Honestly i'm really doing my debute with Microsoft's WPF Framework. What i'm trying to do right now is just a simple dice animation whose value changes when th button is clicked and also affects the scroll. I feel like the binding is correct and everything is fine but when i launch the program, it launches fine but doesn't work. Please i need some help. All code is provided

- When i visualize my code i don't know but i think it' either when i try to affect the same object to both the `dieContol.dataContext` and the `slider.dataContext` or may be my rolling function that's not properly done.
- Here is my `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```cs
namespace Yahtzee
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            slider.DataContext = dieControl.DataContext = new ViewDieModel();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ViewDieModel)dieControl.DataContext).Rolling();
        }
    }
}
```

- Here is my `ControlDie.xaml.cs`

```cs
namespace Yahtzee
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for test.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ControlDie : UserControl
    {
        public ControlDie()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeChanged += (obj, args) => FaceDrawing();
        }
        public int DieValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(DieValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DieValueProperty, value); }
        }
        private void OnDieValueChange()
        {
            FaceDrawing();
        }
        private void FaceDrawing()
        {
            switch (DieValue)
            {
                case 1:
                    FaceOne();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    FaceTwo();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    FaceThree();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    FaceFour();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    FaceFive();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    FaceSix();
                    break;
                default:
                    FaceDrawError();
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void FaceDrawError()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
        }
        private void FaceOne()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.5, .5);
         }
        private void FaceTwo()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.25, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .75);
        }
        private void FaceThree()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.25, .75);
            DrawEllipse(.5, .5);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .25);
        }
        private void FaceFour()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.25, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.25, .75);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .75);
        }
        private void FaceFive()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.25, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.25, .75);
            DrawEllipse(.5, .5);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .75);
        }
        private void FaceSix()
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            DrawEllipse(.25, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.25, .5);
            DrawEllipse(.25, .75);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .25);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .5);
            DrawEllipse(.75, .75);
        }
        private void DrawEllipse(double v1, double v2)
        {
            var dieEllipse = new Ellipse();
            dieEllipse.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            dieEllipse.Width = 5;
            dieEllipse.Height = 5;

            Canvas.SetLeft(dieEllipse, v1 * Width - dieEllipse.Width / 2);
            Canvas.SetTop(dieEllipse, v2 * Height - dieEllipse.Height / 2);
            canvas.Children.Add(dieEllipse);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DieValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DieValue", typeof(int), typeof(ControlDie), new PropertyMetadata(1, DieValueChanged));
        public static void DieValueChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var controlDie = (ControlDie)obj;
            controlDie.OnDieValueChange();
        }
    }
}
```

- Here is my `ControlDie.xaml`

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="Yahtzee.ControlDie"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yahtzee"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="48" d:DesignWidth="48">
    <Border Width="{Binding ElementName=die, Path=Width}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=die, Path=Height}"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="5">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

- Here is my `ViewDieModel.cs`

```cs
namespace Yahtzee
{
    class ViewDieModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int FaceDie
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public void Rolling()
        {
            FaceDie = new Random().Next(6) + 1;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChange(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Here is my `MainWindow.xaml`

```cs
<Window x:Class="Yahtzee.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yahtzee"
        xmlns:myControl ="clr-namespace:Yahtzee"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <myControl:ControlDie x:Name="dieControl" Width="48" Height="48" DieValue="{Binding FaceDie}"/>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="1" Maximum="6" Value="{Binding FaceDie}"/>
        <Button Content="Roll !" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

- Here is my `RollingDice.cs`

```cs
namespace Yahtzee
{
    class RollingDice
    {
        private readonly int[] dice;

        public RollingDice(params int[] dice)
        {
            if(dice.Length != 5)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            else
            {
                this.dice = dice.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return dice[index];
            }
        }
        public IList<int> generateList()
        {
            return new List<int>(dice);
        }
        public ISet<int> generateSet()
        {
            return new HashSet<int>(dice);
        }
        /*public FrequencyTable<int> AsFrequencyTable()
        {
            return new FrequencyTable<int>(dice);
        }*/

    }
}
```

The actual result i'm honestly expecting is just that on clicking the button roll the dice the ControlDie changes so does the Slider but actually nothing changes.

Comment: Not sure why you are binding the Border's Width and Height in the UserControl's XAML. That isn't necessary, and won't work here because there is no element named `die`.

Comment: Besides that, the FaceDie property setter should of course call the NotifyPropertyChange method.

Comment: Please @Clemens can you provide more  details concerning the setter and NotifyPropertyChange ?  Do you mean just calling the method within the setter with no argument ?

Comment: Just search the web for how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens i searched how to better implement it and figured out that the issue was just over my getters and setters. I don't know if i should post it as an answer but anyway thank you.